# Mocking async service in protractor?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, protractor

When I load a view in my Angular app I load some data through angular-ui-routers resolve method.

```
$stateProvider.state({
        name: 'myview',
        component: 'myViewComponent',
        url: '/myView/',
        params:{
            uid:null},
        resolve: {
            customer:($transition$, identifyUser) => {
                'ngInject';
                return identifyUser.identify($transition$.params().uid);
            }
        }
    });
```

The identify method returns a promise and when I'm setting up my protractor tests I decided to mock the identifyUser service so I can go straight into the view without having to load other views i advance. However if I do that my test throws a *Async callback was not invoked within timeout* error message.

The code for the mocked service looks like this

```
browser.addMockModule('appMock', function () {
                angular.module('appMock', ['app', 'ngMockE2E'])
                    .service('identifyUser', function ($q) {
                        return {
                            identify: function (uid) {
                                return $q(function (resolve, reject) {
                                    resolve({
                                        "user_properties": "goes_here"
                                    });
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

I'm clearly missing something, does anyone happen to have a suggestion of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It is not obvious from your code that `appMock` is being loaded in the app. Have you tried to debug `identifyUser` to make sure that mocked service is injected indeed?

Comment: @estus Yes it's working, I've confirmed that.